# How to transfer one table data to another table data with different environment server in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 different databases (A and B) in a SQL Server with different **environment** server.

Database A has around 100 tables out of which I want to synchronize 15 tables from database A to database B.

So if any add / delete / update happens on those 15 tables, then those entries 
should be updated simultaneously in database B.

Same way I need to keep track of update and delete.

Can anybody suggest me what will be the best solution?

Comment: but both database are on different server.

Comment: To get data synchronised you want to use some kind of replication (there are many kinds). Generally this would be approached with SSIS. The important question is: how many records in each table, can you create triggers? How long can you wait to be up to date: 5 secs, 5 mins, 5 hours? Triggers are complex but support faster synchronisation

Comment: Given the emphasis you've placed on "different environment" can the two servers actually talk to each other, or are they isolated? (e.g. dev and prod on separate networks). By "talk" I mean, can you run a command like `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(<connection string for database B on server B>)` on server/database A and get results back from B?

Comment: You have several options for copying data from dbA to dbB - triggers and SSIS (per the above recommendations), [SQL Server replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx), etc. Based on the requirements, limitations and data volumes, some of these options would be more preferable than others.

Comment: Replication and SSIS are not commands that we can provide a one-liner example for, they're processes that need to be configured or code that needs to be built. I've provided a link to replication in my comment, please check that out. And if you're unfamiliar with SSIS, you can look at the documentation for SSIS at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx. Another option is CDC (change data capture): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315.aspx

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate (describe with code/examples) why triggers were not a solution for your problem? Given you've already made a stab at that, it would be a reasonable starting point instead of looking at other data replication techniques (at least, at present).